# How to set Memcached retrieval timeout in Django

Tags: python, django, caching, memcached, amazon-elasticache

How do you change the retrieval timeout for the [Memcached/Elasticache caching backend](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-elasticache) in Django?

I'm using Amazon's Elasticache for caching content in Django, and I'm frequently seeing errors like:

```
  File "/usr/local/myproject/.env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 285, in render
    return nodelist.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/myproject/.env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 830, in render
    bit = self.render_node(node, context)
  File "/usr/local/myproject/.env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 844, in render_node
    return node.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/myproject/.env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/templatetags/static.py", line 109, in render
    url = self.url(context)
  File "/usr/local/myproject/.env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/templatetags/staticfiles.py", line 12, in url
    return staticfiles_storage.url(path)
  File "/usr/local/myproject/.env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/storage.py", line 136, in url
    hashed_name = self.cache.get(cache_key)
  File "/usr/local/myproject/.env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/cache/backends/memcached.py", line 64, in get
    val = self._cache.get(key)
Error: error 31 from memcached_get(myproject:1:staticfiles:27e4bc0): A TIMEOUT OCCURRED
```

I've tried increasing the number of nodes in my Elasticache cluster, but that has had no effect. My next thought was to increase the timeout for the memcached retrieval, but the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/cache/) don't seem to provide an option for this.

There's a "TIMEOUT" option, but that seems to define the default time after which the content *expires*, not the timeout of the HTTP request to the memcached server.

Comment: Is this really the timeout of the HTTP request to the memcached server or maybe rather an internal timeout in the memcached server?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution I went with was to switch my Django cache backend to [django-ft-cache](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-ft-cache/0.1.0), a fault-tolerant version of the standard memcache backend. So now, when a periodic timeout occurs, the cache simply bypasses to a non-cache retrieval of media instead of throwing a 500 error.

Answer (score 4):

There is no setting in django to do that.
Something like this should work, albeit it is quite dirty. Make sure following is executed before cache is created:

```
import memcached; memcached._SOCKET_TIMEOUT = whatever_you_want_it_to_be;
```